# Customizing each element created by the `EditorFor` helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, html-helper

The `EditorFor` helper can be used for automatically scaffolding a model if used as `EditorFor(x=> x, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "x"}})`. The question is that, since it automatically generates labels, fields, and validation messages, is there anyway to customize the styles and classes for each one of these elements in the anonymous type passed into this method (`new { htmlAttributes = ..}`) ?

Comment: What do you want with `new { htmlAttributes = new {@class = "x" }}`, are you want to change class 'x' dynamically from viewmodel property or `ViewBag`?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto: No, `EditorFor` is capable of scaffolding a whole model alongside with individual members of the model. When auto-scaffolding, how can we define css classes for each type of scaffold items such as Label ('text-danger'), field ('form-control'), and validation ('validation-error')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an `EditorTemplate` and the `EditorFor` helper will automatically render your model based on your template and you wouldn't need to rely on the `htmlAttributes` property for customizing your view. The advantage of this is that, your template can be reused over and over specially if it is for types such as `DateTime`, `IFormFile`, etc. You can refer to the following example:

```
UserModelTemplate.cshtml:
-------------------------
@model UserModel 

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="hero-label">
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(m=> m.Username)
         <span class="text-danger">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=> m.Username)
         </span>
     </label>
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.Username, new { @class = "form-control"})
</div>
```

And you can keep going like that. Once you are done developing your template, you can use it together with the `EditorFor` helper (**Place it in the Shared folder, and maybe in a subfolder for better organization**)

```
@Html.EditorFor(model=> model, "UserModelTemplate")
```

Comment: The template should be named the same as the class (`UserModel.cshtml` in this case and placed in the `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder - and then its just `@Html.EditorFor(m => m)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke: That's right, but overriding the default behavior allows you to define multiple templates for a single model or element and use them where applicable.

Comment: Yes, but then you cannot use it for collections. And in any case you can have an `EditorTemplate` for each controller (in the `/Views/ControllerName/EditorTemplates` folders).

Comment: @StephenMuecke: For example, let's say that we need to format a currency field, together with other fields in a model based on a particular location. Then we can do this to dynamically render the proper template.

Comment: I would actually doing something like that using an `HtmlHelper` extension method. I'm not saying you cant do what your suggesting (and I do that occasionally for simple properties), but for complex models, the normal practice is to name your template the same as the model

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Exactly, an extension method in my opinion is the best way for this, but what I explained was just an example to show where this technique would have some advantages. I totally understand your point too.